# Copied Ubuntu 12.04 image to empty DVD but when I try to boot from it I get a message about missing files

Tags: system-installation

I tried installing Ubuntu 12.04 LTS alongside my Windows 8 by downloading the image and copying it to an empty DVD disk.

I tried booting from the CD but it said some files are missing. Anyone know what the problem is?

Answer (score 3):

Just copying image file will not work. Use [ImgBurn](http://www.imgburn.com/) to burn image into your DVD and then try again.

[image]